# Java daemon: "...not allowed access to the window system right now." on boot

Tags: java, daemon, launchd

I have a daemon (/Library/LaunchDaemons/...) configured to launch on boot. However, I get the following error:

```
Nov 17 20:36:24 server.local java[28972]: This user is not allowed access to the window system right now.
Nov 17 20:36:24 server com.apple.launchd[1] (net.java.server): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

I have the daemon configured to run under a daemon user account, and the java command uses `nodisplay`.

Sometimes, when I start, the server works fine. HOWEVER, sometimes (I can't determine what causes it) the server throws up the preceding error. The error repeats, and only a reboot will solve it.

What would cause this, and how do I prevent it from happening? My guess is that Java is trying to display something, but I have no control over the source code so if it is, I need to prevent it from affecting the launchd system in this way.

Comment: Contact the application developer.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sometimes (as in this case) it's not possible to just trust the developer to fix these bugs. Is there some way to either allow the window server to be started, or to force Java to use no display?